# get the memory address of constant variable in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

How can I get the memory address of a constant variable in c++. When I try to get this I get an error.

```
int const nValue = 5;
int * pnPtr = &nValue;
```

The error message is  given below. I'm using visual studio 2010.

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *'
```

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: Read the error message again, it's pretty clear.

Comment: Note that in C++ `nValue` will not have an address at all unless you explicitly take its address as you have (tried to do) here.  If you do not take its address explicitly with the `&nValue` expression, references to the constant `nValue` are replaced with the literal value `5`.

Comment: @Clifford That is only an optimisation that compilers can do under the as-if rule, not a requirement. Were you thinking of `constexpr` instead?

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is there any method to do this?"*

Sure. You need a `const int*` pointer to get this address, as the error message says:

```
   int const nValue = 5;
   const int * pnPtr = &nValue;
// ^^^^^
```

An `int*` pointer would allow to modify the `nValue`, which is not legal, and that's why the compiler complains.

---

As for your comment. A `const int*` can be used to point to a regular `int` **and** a `const int`. The point is just you can't use it to modify the underlying memory at the address it holds.

The pointer variable itself isn't `const` and can be changed to a different address.

If you want both attributes you'll need to write:

```
    const int const * pnPtr = &nValue;
 // ^         ^ 
 // |         + prevents changing the pointer after initialization
 // +- prevents changing the underlying memory
```

Comment: `int nValue = 5;
 int nValue2 = 6;
 
 const int *pnPtr = &nValue;
 cout<< pnPtr <<endl;
 pnPtr = &nValue2; 
 cout<< pnPtr <<endl;`  here pnPtr is constant.  when I run this code it gives different different address. how is it possible.

Comment: @SharthrakNiroshan  What are you actually trying to say with this??

Comment: @SharthrakNiroshan : In the type `const int*` const refers to the data pointed to, not the pointer.  Moreover it may be that the data is not constant, merely that it cannot be modified through this pointer.  To make the pointer itself constant rather then the data, the type would be `int* const`, while constant pointer to a constant integer is `const int* const nValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a pointer to a `const int` value like this:

```
int const *ptr = &nValue;
```

C++ is strict regarding const-correctness, and this is a good thing.